# When are we getting the Dark Theme?

Tags: feature-request, design

This is just a cosmetic issue; one workaround for this is to use the "invert colours" option available within most operating systems - though it has flaws of its own.

But why doesn't ASE simply have a dark theme option in the settings? Stack Overflow already has it, why don't we just import it from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Meta Stack Exchange already has it, why don't we just import it from there?

Because we are completely under control of Stack Exchange, and have no control over when they implement functionality on our site.

You may get some traction asking a similar question on the main [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site although it has been [asked over a decade ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Yup, so on your recommendation I [asked the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385507/1298565) on MSE; it has already been closed as a duplicate . Anyways, thank you for your help!